# vim sparkup tpl

Tags: vim, sparkup

I am using Vim with Sparkup and I have two questions:

1. Sparkup works only with files that end with a HTML extension, however, I would like to use it with TPL, XML, or essentially, any hypertext markup based file.  Is that possible?
2. Unlike the zen-coding plugin it's based on, I can't seem to get zen-coding CSS output. I thought I saw the lack of it in the spark-up files.  Does anyone know how to activate it or easily add it?

(I am using Ubuntu 12.04, 7.3.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sparkup` is a filetype plugin. It depends on the filetype of current file.
When you edit a xml file, `:set ft=html` to change filetype manually.
Then you can use the `sparkup` plugin.

---

If you want vim do it automatically, put this command into your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.xml,*.tpl set ft=html
```

Comment: Thank you! That hit the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Sparkup only deals with HTML. Adding CSS would mean rewriting it. If you want Zencoding why don't you use Zencoding?

Also I don't remember Zencoding doing "css output", whatever that means. Could you provide an example?

Comment: I'll do better, look on page 4. [zencoding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/downloads/detail?name=ZenCodingCheatSheet.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. There's no mention of that in `:h zencoding`, that's a shame. Anyway my answer stands: Sparkup is only for HTML and adding proper CSS may be a non-trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

For your record, a better way is to go into the ftplugin directory of the sparkup extension, make a soft link to the folder html with the name 'xml'. This makes sure that you still have the choice to customize xml and html differently.